# How were these -15 points computed?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes

I noted today that I got -15 points on an [answer of mine](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/105107/security-of-decompression-tools/105108#105108).

[image]

Going to that answer, I however cannot see where the negative score came from:

[image]

How were these -15 points computed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://security.stackexchange.com/users/6341/woj?tab=reputation shows:

[image: show of rep tab showing -15 from unaccept]

So that answer was unaccepted (having being accepted the day before), which takes back the 15 rep originally awarded for the acceptance.